# Solr tagging search results

Tags: solr, solrcloud

My search queries to solr are of the following nature,

```
 (A OR B OR C) OR (X AND Y AND Z) OR ((ABC AND DEF) - XYZ)
```

What I am trying to achieve is when I fire the query the results returned should be able to tagged with which part or the OR resulted in the result. In case all three parts above are applicable then the result should indicate the same. I tried group.query feature, but doesn't seem like it works on solr cloud.

Thanks,

Ayush

Comment: why not issue 3 separate queries?

Comment: potentially I could, but then I would need to merge results from the three and do a lot of processing at my end.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at solr highlighting feature, as your all boolean clauses are distict, it should work.